# Using substring with SpEL in SpringBatch context

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using a stepExecution value to pass on a filename to a spring batch reader. This file name has some garbage values that I would like to get rid of before the value is injected into my reader. I do not want to create a custom reader to handle this, and I know it's possible to do using SpEL, however all examples I find are in Java, and not in the context file.

```
    <bean id="documentSummaryReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="DocumentSummary" />
    <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext['pathResource']}" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="documentSummaryMarshaller" />
</bean>
```

I want to do something like but that doesn't seem to work.

```
`<property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext['pathResource']}.subString(0,10)" />`
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `value="#{stepExecutionContext['pathResource'].substring(0,10)}"`